# Hackerrank: Between Two Sets

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

This is the problem statement:

> You will be given two arrays of integers and asked to determine all
>   integers that satisfy the following two conditions:
>
> 1. The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being considered
> 2. The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array
>
> These numbers are referred to as being between the two arrays. You
>   must determine how many such numbers exist.

I came across this while solving an 'easy' question in Hackerrank. Though it was easy to devise a brute force solution to this problem, I saw a very short solution in the discussions' section:

> 1. Find the LCM of all the integers of array A.
> 2. Find the GCD of all the integers of array B.
> 3. Count the number of multiples of LCM that evenly divides the GCD.

This seems to work but I can't get my head around it. I want to understand that solution because it runs at a better time complexity. Could somebody please explain it?

**Edit:**

I know LCM and GCD. But I think I have lost all my intelligence in order to comprehend a simple solution in hand. I shall appreciate any intuition or instinct regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the LCM of the numbers in A be $L$ and the GCD of the numbers in $B$ be $G$.  A number satisfying condition $1$ is a multiple of each number in $A$, so it's a multiple of $L$.  Similarly, a number satisfying condition $2$ is a divisor of $G$, so the question is simply, "How many multiples of $L$ are divisors of $G$?"